# connecting to mongo shard via java driver 3.2.2

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to connect to mongo query routers in a test environment (I setup just one query router for test -> pointing to a config server (instead of three) which in turn points to a two node shard with no replicas).  I can insert/fetch documents using the mongo shell (and have verified that the documents are going to the sharded nodes).  However, when I try to test the connection to the mongo database, I get the output copied below (code being used is also copied underneath).  I am using mongo database v3.2.0 and java driver v3.2.2 (I am trying to use the async api).

```
[info] 14:34:44.562 227 [main] MongoAuthentication INFO - testing 1
[info] 14:34:44.595 260 [main] cluster INFO - Cluster created with settings {hosts=[192.168.0.1:27018], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=SHARDED, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=30}
[info] 14:34:44.595 260 [main] cluster INFO - Adding discovered server 192.168.0.1:27018 to client view of cluster
[info] 14:34:44.652 317 [main] cluster DEBUG - Updating cluster description to  {type=SHARDED, servers=[{address=192.168.0.1:27018, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]
[info] Outputting database names:
[info] 14:34:44.660 325 [main] cluster INFO - No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=SHARDED, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=192.168.0.1:27018, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
[info] Counting the number of documents
[info] 14:34:44.667 332 [main] cluster INFO - No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primaryPreferred} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=SHARDED, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=192.168.0.1:27018, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
[info]  - Count result: 0
[info] 14:34:45.669 1334 [cluster-ClusterId{value='577414c420055e5bc086c255', description='null'}-192.168.0.1:27018] connection DEBUG - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:1}
```

**part of the code being used**

```
   final MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClientAccessor.INSTANCE.getMongoClientInstance();

    final CountDownLatch listDbsLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    System.out.println("Outputting database names:");
    mongoClient.listDatabaseNames().forEach(new Block<String>() {
        @Override
        public void apply(final String name) {
            System.out.println(" - " + name);
        }
    }, new SingleResultCallback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(final Void result, final Throwable t) {
            listDbsLatch.countDown();
        }
    });
```

The enum being used is responsible for reading config options and passing a MongoClient reference to its caller.  The enum itself calls other classes which I can copy as well if needed.  I have the following option configured for ReadPreference:

```
mongo.client.readPreference=PRIMARYPREFERRED
```

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong or might have misinterpreted?  The goal is to connect to the shard via the mongos (query router) so that I can insert/fetch documents in the Mongo shard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongo shard setup (query router, config and shard with replica sets) was not correctly configured.  Ensure that the config server(s) replica set is launched first, mongos (query router) is brought up and points to these config servers, the mongo shards are brought up and then the shards are registered via the query router (mongos) as well as the collection is enabled for sharding.  Obviously, make sure that the driver is connecting to the mongos (query router) process.